# Multiple receivers for IPNs

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Is it possible to receive the same IPN at multiple endpoints? I can pass a NOTIFY_URL e.g. for ExpressCheckout, but I may also setup an URL in my PayPal account. Will IPNs be send to both? Only one? Which one has preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have IPN configured in your PayPal account profile that will act as a default catch-all.  If you then set an IPN URL via the NotifyURL parameter of payment requests that would override the value set in your profile.

If you need to have IPN data sent to more than one IPN URL with a single transaction you can [daisy-chain the IPN scripts](http://go.developer.ebay.com/content/daisy-chaining-ipns).  PayPal would send the IPN to your URL, which could then forward that IPN data on to as many secondary URL's as you need to.

Comment: I suspected this would be the case. Daisy-chaining might work in some cases, however I don't have control over the code that is using the account to manage payments. I was hoping I could double-check transactions by receiving IPNs as well. But thanks!